# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [A] from the managed type [T] is not present

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I'm trying to do a search page that retrieves some data from my database using JPA 2.0 Criteria API. I'm getting the same exception error everytime I try to do the search.

Here is my search method:

```
public List<Matches> search(SearchCommercialsDTO searchCommercialsDTO) {

    CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Matches> criteria = builder.createQuery( Matches.class );
    Root<Matches> matchesRoot = criteria.from( Matches.class );
    criteria.select( matchesRoot );

    List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    Predicate date, equipmentName, channelCode, advertiserName, agencyName, productName, duration;

    if(!ObjectUtil.isEmpty(searchCommercialsDTO.getEquipmentName())) {
        equipmentName = builder.like(matchesRoot.get("ID_RECORDER_FILES.EQUIPMENT_NAME").as(String.class), searchCommercialsDTO.getEquipmentName());
        predicateList.add(equipmentName);
    }
    if(!ObjectUtil.isEmpty(searchCommercialsDTO.getChannelCode())) {
        channelCode = builder.equal(matchesRoot.get("ID_RECORDER_FILES.CHANNEL_CODE"), searchCommercialsDTO.getChannelCode());
        predicateList.add(channelCode);
    }
    if(!ObjectUtil.isEmpty(searchCommercialsDTO.getAdvertiserName())) {
        advertiserName = builder.equal(matchesRoot.get("ID_SOURCE_MATERIAL.ADVERTISER_NAME"), searchCommercialsDTO.getAdvertiserName());
        predicateList.add(advertiserName);
    }
    if(!ObjectUtil.isEmpty(searchCommercialsDTO.getAgencyName())) {
        agencyName = builder.equal(matchesRoot.get("ID_SOURCE_MATERIAL.AGENCY_NAME"), searchCommercialsDTO.getAgencyName());
        predicateList.add(agencyName);
    }
    if(!ObjectUtil.isEmpty(searchCommercialsDTO.getProductName())) {
        productName = builder.equal(matchesRoot.get("ID_SOURCE_MATERIAL.PRODUCT_NAME"), searchCommercialsDTO.getProductName());
        predicateList.add(productName);
    }

    Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[predicateList.size()];
    predicateList.toArray(predicates);
    criteria.where(predicates);

    return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

When it tries to execute this part:

```
equipmentName = builder.like(matchesRoot.get("ID_RECORDER_FILES.EQUIPMENT_NAME").as(String.class), searchCommercialsDTO.getEquipmentName());
```

It throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [ID_RECORDER_FILES.EQUIPMENT_NAME] from the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@112477145:Matches [ javaType: class net.checkmidia.auditoria.entity.Matches descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(net.checkmidia.auditoria.entity.Matches --> [DatabaseTable(MATCHES)]), mappings: 12]] is not present.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.ManagedTypeImpl.getAttribute(ManagedTypeImpl.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.FromImpl.get(FromImpl.java:312)
    at net.checkmidia.auditoria.business.MatchesBO.search(MatchesBO.java:50)
    at net.checkmidia.auditoria.session.MatchesSession.searchMatches(MatchesSession.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5388)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor72.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5360)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 51 more
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: show us your ejb exception trace.

Comment: Sorry about that!! The exception trace is now on the question.
I think the problem is about the fact that i need to access some data of other table on the database that is linked with the main table called, in this case, Matches. Thats why my matchesRoot.get is with the string "idRecorderFiles.someattribute" in some parts of my code, but I dont know if this really works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
matchesRoot.get("ID_RECORDER_FILES.EQUIPMENT_NAME")
```

to

```
matchesRoot.get("ID_RECORDER_FILES").get("EQUIPMENT_NAME")
```

and also verify that "ID_RECORDER_FILES" is the name of a field of your Java class `Matches`, and "EQUIPMENT_NAME" is the name of a field in the class of the "ID_RECORDER_FILES" field.

The method [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) takes the name of an attribute, so you must pass just the id and then use the resulting [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html) to get the field contained in that object.